# .htaccess Rewrite rules for sorting variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, sorting, mod-rewrite

php to display results. URLs are like that...

```
www.example.com/Vehicle/Car
www.example.com/Vehicle/Car/Maruti
```

Rewrite rule so far i have applied for that are and these are working perfectly for me.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /list.php?type1=$1&type2=$2&type3=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /list.php?type1=$1&type2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Now i want to sort all my results on basis of price, model and visits and want to add sort variable at the end of url to sort results. e.g.

```
www.example.com/Vehicle/Car/?sort='sort-value'
www.example.com/Vehicle/Car/Maruti/?sort='sort-value'
```

What Rewrite rule do i need to apply for that ?? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Your current rewrite rules should already provide for what you want.

You have specified the `QSA` flag which will append the `sort='sort-value'` to your rewritten value.

Comment: please specify exactly what 'this URL' is.

Comment: Its www.example.com/list.php?type1=Vehicle&type2=Car&type3=Maruti

Comment: After adding a sort variable it becomes www.example.com/list.php?type1=Vehicle&type2=Car&type3=Marut‌​i&sort='sort-value'

Comment: And when i go to www.example.com/Vehicle/Car/Marut‌​i/?sort='sort-value', I get 404 error

The requested URL /Vehicle/Car/Maruti/.php was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Something is adding .php to the end of your URL. Find and resolve that and it should work

Comment: Hi i have gotten my error...It is the slash at end after Maruti....www.example.com/Vehicle/Car/Marut‌​i?sort='sort-value' is working